# java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer

Tags: java

I have developed a Java application and bundled it into a JAR file (executable).

Now when I am executing the jar using command `Java -jar EncryptionUtility.jar > log.txt` following exception is appearing:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:204)
        at TripleDESBC.readKey(TripleDESBC.java:85)
        at TripleDESBCUtil.decrypt3DES(TripleDESBCUtil.java:112)
        at CommonUtil.setKeys(CommonUtil.java:308)
        at CommonUtil.encryptAndSign(CommonUtil.java:575)
        at CommonUtil$5.actionPerformed(CommonUtil.java:295)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:93)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK
release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)
        at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyPolicySigned(JarVerifier.java:328)
        at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:378)
```

I have checked on the internet but found no good solution or explanation on this issue. Please help..

Comment: This error should only ever occur when you messed with the policy files in your JDK or JRE installation. It's basically unrelated to what your program is doing (except it will only happen when you try to use crypto, but it does not indicate a fault in your application).

Comment: Actually, its crashing my application. When I click on the button the program decrypts a password stored in dat files.

Comment: Now I have to distribute this jar to other people around. Will it execute successfully on their platforms? assuming that there java installation is fine. or they have to compile first?

Comment: Probably yes, simply download and install a local copy  of the JRE to verify this though.

Answer (score 0):

It was occuring because my Java version was pointed to wrong path and it has different policy files. Thats why it was throwing this error.

Setting java home and path resolved my issue:)